# python 3 best practice for string format of messages

Tags: python, logging

I wonder what is better practice when using python 3 logging.
a) logger.info("my message args are %s, %s", "a", "b")
b) logger.info("my message args are {}, {}".format("a", "b"))
is the first option more quick?
I find the second option convenient since I can easily replace the logger.info with print command.

Comment: Relevant: [Python: Logging TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting](//stackoverflow.com/q/12843099)

Comment: As Martijn already gave an perfect answer: 'You cannot use new-style formatting when using the logging module; use `%s` instead of `{}`'

Comment: @Ludisposed: logging can take care of the actual templating step. For that feature, only `%s` is supported. If you ignore that feature, there is nothing specific about logging here, and the question is a dupe.